# Why JPA @Transient does not work with array properties when using Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transient

When I use `@Transient` on an array property, my application fails to start. I'm using Spring 3.1 + Hibernate 4.2.3.

> Maven configuration

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

> Entity class

```
    private Map<String,Integer>[] toyCountMapArr=null;

    @Transient
    public Map<String, Integer>[] getToyCountMapArr() {
      return toyCountMapArr;
    }
```

Error message at application startup:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext-hibernate.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No PropertyTypeExtractor available for type void 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.__refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No PropertyTypeExtractor available for type void 
    at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.toXType(JavaReflectionManager.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaXProperty.create(JavaXProperty.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.getXProperty(JavaReflectionManager.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaXClass.getDeclaredMethodProperties(JavaXClass.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaXClass.getDeclaredProperties(JavaXClass.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaXClass.getDeclaredProperties(JavaXClass.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.determineDefaultAccessType(InheritanceState.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:665)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3512)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3466)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1355)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1756)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1840)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:189)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:350)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 56 more
```

All of the following declarations work:

```
private Map<String,Integer> toyCountMap

private String[] toyCountMapArr=null

private HashMap<String,Integer>[] toyCountMapArr=null
```

Is this happening because `Map<String, Integer>` is not `Serializable` so `Map<String,Integer>[]` can't be serialized?

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not eagerly initializing the field?  Why should it be null at all, ever?

Comment: JPA standard `@Transient` can be used on __any__ field. If your JPA provider has an issue with it then raise a bug on it.

Comment: @Makoto @NeilS thanks your help, but if my property is `private Map<String,Integer> toyCountMap`, or if my property is `private String[] toyCountMapArr=null`, then both are working right, only when `private Map<String,Integer>[] toyCountMapArr=null`, it will fail,  so is it because the `Map<String,Integer>` is not a Serializable Object, so `Map<String,Integer>[]` can't be Serialized at second time

Comment: and if `private HashMap<String,Integer>[] toyCountMapArr=null`,  it's also fine. I have no idea

Comment: Serialisation is irrelevant to a JPA provider supporting `@Transient` on a field, it doesn't need to "serialise" an object, it needs to persist it to a database. JPA provider I use can handle such things

Comment: You have been hit by [this Hibernate bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HCANN-29). As noted in the linked bug description changing to `Collection<Map<String, Integer>>` will resolve the error.